# Hack : Send data from pi3 to server cloud

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi3

I want to send data from raspberry pi3 to server cloud use python
I decided use 'mysql.connector' lib
but my friend say that : the lib support for send data to cloud (ex: mysql.connector, MysqlDb,....)  very easy hack user and password of database because when use this lib, you may open port, this is chance for hackers
If you dont want hacker attack, you may use 'http'(urllib3) to send data to server cloud
My friend is right or wrong?? 
thanks all

Comment: What is "cloud" here. You have a remote mysql server to which you are wanting to send data from your pi via python? It would be ill advised to open up your remote mysql server to the internet, but depending on what your "Cloud" is you could create a security group that has access for just your IP to allow traffic through the mysql port.

Comment: "cloud" is mysql server, I buy a host and setup mysql server to host

Comment: OK. I think your friend is mostly accurate. If you have the ability, on your host, to only allow connections through on the mysql port (TCP 3306) for your external IP that your Rasbperri Pi sits behind, then you can safely use mysql.connector. Alternatively you could set up an SSH tunnel to forward traffic from your Pi's localhost 3306 to Remote (mysql server) port 3306 and then use Mysql.Connector against localhost (which will forward). I think that's a little round about though. Ultimately you don't want your MySQL server's Port 3306 to publicly accessible.